# Free forum components to integrated with website in jsp

Tags: jsp

I would like to include a `forum` to a website.
The website is build in `jsp`, thus, I wish to know is there any forum components on the website that I can make use of that are well integrated with the `jsp`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try jforum: http://www.jforum.net/

It is easy to use.